# Set process title in visual studio attach to process c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, process, set, title

I want to set the process title of my console application in the **attach to process** dialog of **visual studio**.
I tried to set the assembly name, process description, etc.. but it didn't work.
How can I achieve this in C#?

[image]

Comment: I believe the title will come from the mainwindowhandle's title.  Do you have a form?

Comment: No I want to set this title in a C# console application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Console.Title = "Your title here";
```

[image]

Comment: This change the console window title, but the process title in the attach to process dialog is still blank.

Comment: @AntoineLafarge Is your project a Console Application? How are you launching it?

Comment: Okay it works when I launch the binary from the explorer, but it does not work when I use the Visual Studio ctrl + F5 shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is for debugging, open a new blank form at to of program and close it at end...that'll work...I'll see if there's another idea

If there's no form, process.mainwindowtitle is blank

Comment: Since this is for debugging, open a new blank form at to of program and close it at end...that'll work...I'll see if there's another idea

Comment: Opening a dummy form will have to do, process.mainwindowtitle will be blank if there's no visible form

Comment: Yes when I create a new form application, the title is the form window title.

Comment: Then there's your answer 

Comment: But I want to achieve this on a console application. Do you know how the form is changing this title?

Comment: You don't need a form application to create a dummy form, do you need the code for that?

Comment: Oh ok I see, but it looks like a hack :(